# using Sitecore fileds in MVC models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, sitecore, mapper

I watched some videos about implementing IRenderingModel interface and inherit renderingModel class in order to use Sitecore data template fields in MVC models (like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dW_rQp9bMmE&index=2&list=PL1jJVFm_lGnweAZ0jF1SgfooRv3h9jiEY )
but as far as I understood, in MVC side, all properties are declared as HtmlString; hence I'm looking for an effective way to use Sitecore fields in MVC model

Below are defined data templates:

### News

Title          Text
Description    RichText
Image         Image
Category      MultiList

### Category

Title     Text
ID        Int

Comment: I'd highly recommend you use an ORM like Glass Mapper: http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc

Comment: @afshin is there a reason you do not want to use a controller rendering? When you create a rendering view model (IRenderingModel), the code is un-testable. Best practice is to use a controller rendering and have all your manipulation in the repositories/services.

Comment: No need for a controller rendering for basic views. A view rendering would be just fine.

Comment: @dnstommy I use controller rendering and as I mentioned, I have some fields like Title and Image and I think l need to map these fields into MVC model.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is starting with [Habitat](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/wiki/) and its way of work.

Is a demo project including some Sitecore best practices so you can learn to things in the best way.

This video you are watching is not the proper way to proceed or at least is not the way it's being handled by most Sitecore developers.

Once you start with habitat there is some useful [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2CELqflPhm0&list=PL87NYg4HBdLGrScgxywDIiCFb8IIctf3k) to get started. It will take you some time to get started, but I really think is the best way for you to proceed.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What you want it to be able to edit the sitecore items, in the editor when the content is coming from an MVC controller. What you want to do is translate the editable field into an IHtmlString (Html field) and send it to the UI. Then if the page is in edit mode, show the editable text. Else, just show the value (Text field).

You could also just send the HTML field and let the editor show the editable content when in edit mode, or not.

But to bring it around to what Jammy said, Glass Mapper does all this with the @Editable field.

TestController.cs

```
using Bonfire.Feature.Header.Models;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers;

namespace Sitecore.Feature.Header.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : SitecoreController
    {
        public ActionResult Header()
        {
            var item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/settings/header");

            var header = new HeaderModel
            {
                Header = new StringModel
                {
                    Text = item.Fields["HeaderText"].Value,
                    Html = new MvcHtmlString(Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.FieldRenderer.Render(item, "HeaderText"))
                }
            };

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

HeaderModel.cs

```
namespace Sitecore.Feature.Header.Models
{
    public class HeaderModel
    {
        public StringModel Header { get; set; }
    }
}
```

StringModel.cs

```
using System.Web;

namespace Sitecore.Feature.Header.Models
{
    public class StringModel
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public IHtmlString Html { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Header.cshtml

```
@model Sitecore.Feature.Header.Models.HeaderModel

@if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor)
{
    <div>
        @Model.Header.Text
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div>
        @Model.Header.Html
    </div>
}
```